# Why am I finding greater power with a coarser level of randomization?

Tags: stata, experiment-design, statistical-power

I am working on a Monte Carlo power analysis for an experiment about the hiring of teachers in schools. We can randomize the treatment at the school level or at the applicant-school level. I was expecting to find lower power when randomizing at the school level. However, I am finding the opposite. The (simplified) code below produces power of .704 at the school level and .514 at the applicant-school level.

I am trying to figure out whether I have made a stupid error somewhere or if this is even possible. A wrinkle is that we don't expect the treatment to have a *direct* effect on hiring, but rather to reduce measurement error in a screening score. Our estimate of interest is the interaction term between the screening score and treatment. Since this is unusual, it makes me wonder if maybe randomizing at the school level should somehow actually provide higher power?

I am hoping someone else will have some intuition on what might be going on here.

I have provided some (simplified from how I am actually running it) Stata code of the simulation below. It's a bit long, apologies, but is well commented.

```
clear
set obs 1

*level = [0, randomize at schools], [1, randomize at applicant-school]
foreach level in 0 1 {

    *Store the number of significant effects found (for power)
    g sig_hired_`level' = 0

    forvalues b = 1(1)500 {
        quietly {
            preserve
            clear

            noisily display "Working on randomization `level', iteration `b' of 500 at $S_TIME"
            *Generate schools based on 52 schools
            set obs 52
            g school = _n
            g school_quality = rnormal()
            *If treatment is randomized at school level, randomize schools into treatment
            *Generate clustering variable "clus" at the school level
            if `level' == 0 {
                g treat = runiform() > .5
                g clus = school
            }

            *Change the level of observation from "one obs per school" to "one obs per job application" based on provided number of jobs (390) and applications per job (6)
            expand 390
            g app = _n
            expand 6

            *Generate teachers to go with the applications based on 878 teachers among all the job openings
            g tch_id = floor(runiform()*878)

            *Underlying true teacher quality
            g id_quality = rnormal()
            sort id app
            replace id_quality = id_quality[_n-1] if tch_id == tch_id[_n-1]

            *Assign treatment at applicant/school level
            *Cluster at teacher level
            if `level' == 1 {
                g treat = runiform() > .5
                sort tch_id school
                replace treat = treat[_n-1] if tch_id == tch_id[_n-1] & school == school[_n-1]
                g clus = tch_id
            }

            *Generate the observed screening score based on true ability and random noise. Treatment leads to less noise, effect size set to .2 but problem shows up with others
            g screen60 = id_quality + rnormal(0,1 - treat*.05)

            *Offer a job to the person with the highest screening score in that job
            gsort app -screen60
            g hired = app != app[_n-1]

            *Create interaction term (working with an old version of Stata that doesn't do them on the fly)
            g treatquality = id_quality*treat

            *Predict whether or not true ability is more predictive of being hired under the treatment
            logit hired id_quality treat treatquality, vce(cluster clus)
            test treatquality
            local hired_scr = (r(p) <= .05)

        }
    restore
    *Store which significant coefficients were found above
    replace sig_hired_`level' = sig_hired_`level' + 1 if `hired_scr' == 1
    }
}

foreach var of varlist sig_* {
    replace `var' = `var' / 500
}
summ sig_*
```

Comment: There are many sources of variation.  It looks like your approach has found that school-to-school variation is a significant source.  May I make a (possibly strange) recommendation?  You can use a random forest to determine variable importance.  If you have "school" as a column and "teacher" as a column you can determine which has a higher influence on variation.  After you have accounted for school-to-school variation then you can look at teacher-to-teacher variation.  School-to-school might be driven by principal, community, budget, facilities... understanding its source can improve outcomes

Comment: If you are using "stata" then you might want to put a tag for it in your question.  This will resource stata users who might appreciate and have relevant answers for your question.

Comment: This data is all simulated, and the same controls are used in each case. The variable importance for school and teacher are whatever I set them at. What's varying is the level at which the treatment is randomized, not the variation controlled for in the final model. So I don't think this really gets at the issue. Thanks for the Stata-tagging tip though!